# How do conditionally render a node based on a field at a specific index when mapping out elements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dataset like this:

```
const data = [
  {id: '123', distance_miles: 300, name: 'Karen', ...},
  {id: '124', distance_miles: 50, name: 'Bob', ...},
  {id: '125', distance_miles: 26, name: 'Kim', ...},
  // ....
];
```

And I'm using that to render some elements in React:

```
<>
  {data.map(d => <div key={d.id}>{d.name}</div>)}
  // ....
</>
```

However I want to insert a Node that specifically inserted in the third index if the `distance_miles` fields in this complete dataset are **all** above `25`.

What I've tried is mapping over the dataset and filtering out `distance_miles`, but I not sure where to proceed from there.

What I've also tried to looking into `.splice()`, but not sure how to use that considering the conditional.

What I've also done is tried to save the rendered array into a variable:

```
const renderedData = data.map(d => <div key={d.id}>{d.name}</div>)
// splice node into renderedData?
```

but I'm hitting a roadblock on how to even read the `distance_mile` field like that. Does anyone know how to approach something like this?

Comment: Can you show expected output? The question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a helper function which would check if every `distance_miles` prop is higher than 25:

```
const isEveryHigher = (arr) => arr.every(({ distance_miles }) => distance_miles > 25);
```

And then use a conditional mapping:

```
(isEveryHigher(data) 
    ? [...data.slice(0, 3), <SomeNode />, ...data.slice(3)] 
    : data)
.map(() => ...); // render your stuff
```

Comment: Amazing. I had to change the logic a little but this put me on the right track. THANK you so much!!!